# Parallel MPPT and buck with PV to power an ESP32 via USB

Tags: usb, buck

[image]
I have a 100w 20v 5A PV that is being used to charge a 72v SLA pack. The MPPT has the 12v-60v input and output 24v-72v range I need. It doesn't have a USB port built in though.

I'd like to have this MPPT https://gotronik.pl/images/MPT-7210A.pdf in parallel with a buck converter, to be used to provide 160mA at 5v via USB to an ESP32 dev board. I'm assuming around 200mA current draw from the ESP32 + buck converter. The question: would having the buck converter in parallel on the MPPT input, cause problems with the MPPT algorithm? I don't want to damage the MPPT by overheating it for eg.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Draw a block diagram please.

Comment: Thanks StarCat and Andy, updated.